# How to maximize a function with respect to some x?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to maximize the following function with respect to p1_current, how do I do this?

```
pwin_1 + Q1[p1_current, p2_current] - p1_current
```

As background, I start with randomizing prices, defining the probability of winning, and set up a matrix:

```
p2_current = random.randint(0,6)

if p1_current < p2_current:
  pwin_1 = (0.5)*pwin_1 + 0.5
elif p1_current >= p2_current:
  pwin_1 = (0.5)*pwin_1

Q1 = np.array(np.zeros([7,7]))
Q1 = Q1.astype(int)
```

I am very confused as to how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use minima and Maxima for this.
To get derivative of function in python proceed as shown

[code to find derivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5AF3.jpg)
You could also use the num py diff function.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but because p1_current is defined by an if statement, doesn't that make it discrete and therefore not differentiable?